# 2 step problem: Share info between 2 user controls on a page, Display info in a scrolling list or gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page with multiple user controls on it. In one user control, I have a set of checkboxes that set filters on what to display in a tree view, also in the same user control. In another user control, I have a list view (or gridview, haven't decided yet) That needs to display some information based on the filters that are defined, and the tree node selected in the previous user control.

The listview, or gridview, needs to scroll, displaying X(say 10) amount of records at a time. Depending on what the user has selected, there can be up to 28,000 records to display, so we only want to go to the database to get a small amount of records at a time, and update the list on the fly.

Comment: how can i share data between 2 user controls, and how can i display the information in a scrolling listview or gridview?

Comment: Ashton, you can share Data between controls using the ViewState for the page or the Session.  That being said, through your description you probably want to be passing data between your controls rather then sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your "Search" control is going to have to raise an event to it's parent control.
If the parent control will then perform the search based on the specified criteria.

The parent control can either pass the result dataset to the "Grid" control or if it is the "Grid" control, display the data.

It's hard to get more specific without more of a concrete example.